# Dual boot Win10 + Arch Linux on SSD, showing HDD but not recognizing partitions

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot

Had Windows + Linux Mint dual boot on HDD initially. Replaced this with installing Windows and Arch on an SSD. Now Windows shows HDD partitions as D and E drives, but Arch does not show these partitions. I still haven't removed Linux Mint from HDD and it is mounted on my Arch, but D and E drives are still missing.

Result of running `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: CT500P1SSD8                             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4EF518B6-50C8-46C3-8F19-C8FE91FA6F1A

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1        34     32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2     32768 341891071 341858304   163G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 341891072 976773134 634882063 302.7G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HTS721010A9
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2B21729B-367C-4679-8124-ED7409730921

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1085440    1290239     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1290240    1292287       2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda4     1292288    1323007      30720    15M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     1323008 1735417855 1734094848 826.9G Microsoft LDM data
/dev/sda6  1735417856 1953523711  218105856   104G Linux filesystem
```

sda6 is my Linux Mint partition and `/dev/sda5` has my D and E drive partitions but they are not recognized in Linux. How do I fix this without formatting the drive?

**Edit:** I tried running ldmtool to mount the dynamic disk. Here are the results:

`sudo ldmtool scan /dev/sda5`

```
[
  "0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40"
]
```

`sudo ldmtool show diskgroup 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40`

```
{
  "name" : "DESKTOP-0S6HGK5-Dg0",
  "guid" : "0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40",
  "volumes" : [
    "Volume2",
    "Volume1"
  ],
  "disks" : [
    "Disk1"
  ]
}
```

`sudo ldmtool create all`

```
Unable to create volume Volume2 in disk group 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40: ldm_vol_DESKTOP-0S6HGK5-Dg0_Volume2: Stacking NODE_DEL [verify_udev]
Unable to create volume Volume1 in disk group 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40: ldm_vol_DESKTOP-0S6HGK5-Dg0_Volume1: Stacking NODE_DEL [verify_udev]
[]
```

How do I fix this `Stacking NODE_DEL [verify_udev]`?

Edit 2:

I used `sudo ldmtool create volume 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40 Volume1` but it gave me the same error as before.

`sudo ldmtool show volume 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40 Volume1` returned

```
{
  "name" : "Volume1",
  "guid" : "0c9f44d2-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40",
  "type" : "spanned",
  "size" : 1048543232,
  "chunk-size" : 0,
  "hint" : "D:",
  "partitions" : [
    "Disk1-01",
    "Disk1-03"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Microsoft LDM is a filesystem peculiar to Microsoft. I believe it was invented for NT4.

Comment: Dynamic/LDM was a proprietary work around for the MBR 4 primary partition limit. But with gpt the limit is 128 partitions (or more). So how did it get converted to LDM? https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html

Comment: Your D and E partitions seem to be wrapped in what Microsoft calls "Logical Disk Manager".  The [Arch Wiki on this topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dynamic_disks) might help

Comment: ldmtool showed me the drives but creating volume resulted in error. Can you help? I've edited the question.

Comment: @GracefulRestart, it would be great if you can have a look

Comment: According to your output, the LDM data is on two separate disks (`/dev/sda5` is the data but `/dev/sda3` is the metadata).  See if running `sudo ldmtool scan` picks up the metadata as well.  You could also try to manage each volume within LDM separately instead of using `all`: `sudo ldmtool create volume 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40 Volume1`.  If it still fails, show the information for each volume: `sudo ldmtool show volume 0c9f43d0-ddc1-11eb-aa0a-00e18c420e40 Volume1`

Comment: @GracefulRestart Volume1 returned two partitions in the same volume. But creation of volume returned the same error as before. What should I do now?